# A few Questions Regarding the Security of JSON Web Tokens?

Tags: api, security, authentication, jwt

I've been working on an Android/IOS application that uses a Tomcat API to send/receive data,login,logout,etc. My primary form of authentication is via JSON web tokens with HMAC using SHA-512. The authentication is performed as usual. The user provides their credentials (userID and password) to login the first time. The server verifies the credentials and if they are correct, it generates and returns a JWT to the user which they can use to authenticate themselves in future requests. The token contains a custom claim that specifies the userID, which is used to know which user is making the request. I did some research regarding JWTs and opinions are mixed regarding many issues. I have a couple of questions that I hope you can shed light on:

1- Is it enough to use JWT as the sole authentication mechanism of my API?

2- In terms of security, is there a difference between JWT using HMAC and JWT using RSA?

3- Ideally, where should I store the symmetric signing key that I am signing my tokens with? Currently, I am passing the key directly to the function that generates my tokens. Is it safe to do this?

4- Should I change the signing key periodically for better security?

5- Can I trust the userID claim that I inserted into the token to identify the user making the request?

6- Is there an "ideal" expiration time for a token? Some people suggest as little as 15 mins while others say 3 hours is fine.

7- Should I worry about limiting the number of tokens that a particular user can have? A user may have multiple mobile devices and at any time may have multiple tokens. In this case, there is nothing stopping the user from obtaining thousands of tokens from my server provided that they have their credentials. Should I implement some mechanism (eg: database) to keep track of the tokens that a user has? This seems to defeat the purpose of JWTs and add complexity if I have to make additional database queries when verifying/generating a token.

8- Do I have to worry about revoking tokens? Some suggest that having tokens with a short expiration time is sufficient. Others point out that you can never have a true logout mechanism if you don't revoke tokens once the user logs out of the application. Is it wrong to just wait for the tokens to expire? In terms security, when would I ever need to revoke the token?

Sorry for the long post. I have been worrying about the best approach to handling these issues. I appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: I'd advise you to split out these over different questions: a) people are more likely to answer short questions b) it will be more useful for others searching for the same answer to one specific question c) it would make it more independent of your system implementation/problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1- Is it enough to use JWT as the sole authentication mechanism of my
> API?

Generally yes, as long as the "signing key" is of sufficient strength (if HMAC then 128 bit, generated by a CSPRNG). I'll cover whether it "is enough" in my other answers below.

> 2- In terms of security, is there a difference between JWT using HMAC
> and JWT using RSA?

The HMAC signing key could potentially be brute forced if one of sufficient entropy is not selected. RSA should not have this flaw as the keys are long and should inherently have enough entropy in their generation process already.

> 3- Ideally, where should I store the symmetric signing key that I am
> signing my tokens with? Currently, I am passing the key directly to
> the function that generates my tokens. Is it safe to do this?

You should store this in an application configuration file that is unreadable via the web. This enables it to be different per deployment (e.g. tokens provided in your pre-release environment cannot be used for authentication in your production environment).

> 4- Should I change the signing key periodically for better security?

No, not if it is of sufficient strength (128 bit entropy, as above) and not if it hasn't been leaked.

> 5- Can I trust the userID claim that I inserted into the token to
> identify the user making the request?

Yes, that's the whole point. If your HMAC is calculated over this claim then it can't be altered.

> 6- Is there an "ideal" expiration time for a token? Some people
> suggest as little as 15 mins while others say 3 hours is fine.

This depends on the "risk appetite" of the application. For example, if your application was under PCI compliance, this would be 15 minutes. If you are happy for users to leave their sessions open for longer then this can be increased.

> 7- Should I worry about limiting the number of tokens that a
> particular user can have? A user may have multiple mobile devices and
> at any time may have multiple tokens. In this case, there is nothing
> stopping the user from obtaining thousands of tokens from my server
> provided that they have their credentials. Should I implement some
> mechanism (eg: database) to keep track of the tokens that a user has?
> This seems to defeat the purpose of JWTs and add complexity if I have
> to make additional database queries when verifying/generating a token.

No, as you say this defeats the object of JWTs in the first place. If you're allowing user sessions to be managed client-side though JWTs, then you should not be keeping track of sessions server-side. Since tokens are client-side it should be of no concern to your application how many have been generated as there is no additional overhead for you. If you are concerned about multiple users logging in as the same account then JWTs is not the way to go - a server-side managed system would be better where tokens issued can be limited to a number of simultaneous sessions only.

> 8- Do I have to worry about revoking tokens? Some suggest that having
> tokens with a short expiration time is sufficient. Others point out
> that you can never have a true logout mechanism if you don't revoke
> tokens once the user logs out of the application. Is it wrong to just
> wait for the tokens to expire? In terms security, when would I ever
> need to revoke the token?

Again, this boils down to "risk appetite". If a password is compromised, it is harder to revoke existing sessions that may have been made by an attacker. Similar with logout links as all you can do is respond to the client to request deletion of the cookie.

One way is to include the date and time of the last password change in the JWT, which is included in the HMAC calculation. Then this would be checked on every request to find out if it matched the value in your database. If it doesn't, then you would reject the authentication token and force the user to relogin. This is one way you can do revocation with JWTs.

Logout is trickier as one logout request would logout all sessions if you included a "logout date/time" in the token, that was checked server-side. Again, your risk appetite would decide whether this is worth implementing, or whether it was just easier to set a short expiration period at risk of any tokens retrieved by an attacker could continue to be renewed indefinitely (or until the user changed their password if you go with my earlier solution).

### General on expiry/password change

Another approach is to use JWT's with short expiry times, but refresh these periodically using a background request, or regularly when processing other requests. This way you can keep the user logged in for more convenient time periods for them, but in the case of a revoked account or changed password, you could then redirect them to the login screen rather than refreshing their JWT with a longer expiry.

Comment: Thanks a lot SilverlightFox. Your answer was really helpful.